# Kafka Consumer stops consuming when Scheduled job starts spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

My spring boot application have a kafka consumer and a scheduled job. The problem is Kafka consumer stops consuming until the scheduled job is finished. I want the kafka consumer keeps consuming concurrently while she job doing its thing.

Any idea about this behaviour ?

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "sometopic", concurrency = "2" )
    public void batchListen(@Payload List<String> messages) {
}



 @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "30000" , initialDelay = 10000)
    public void job() {
       // some job action 
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that they don't use the same blocking code? So, when `job()` calls something the `batchListen()` is waiting on that to be finished.

Comment: yes they are not using the same blocking code @ArtemBilan

Comment: Any chances to give us a simple project on GitHub to reproduce and investigate what is going on?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense; the listener runs on its own dedicated threads (from a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` by default. Take a thread dump to see what those threads are doing while the scheduled task is running. DEBUG logging should help too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem will be to introduce multithreading. To run kafka consumer in a separate thread and scheduled job in another separate thread.

For the scheduled job you can use the Spring `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
ScheduledFuture<Object> resultFuture =
   executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 10, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```